# how a index file affects your spring mvc project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i have a spring mvc web application project that i'm doing with spring tools suite, i am using maven to add my dependencies and thymeleaf to do my view.

I have my project configured in a code-based approach i dont have xml files.

"i DONT have the default page that you can configure with"

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I HAVE a index.html file in my webapp folder, i have all my css, js, ajax folders in there, i am not using the web-inf folder to put my .html files

My problem is that when i put this URL `http://localhost:8080/myapp/` my application should go to the page that this controller is in charge

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String home() {
    logger.info("***HOME***");

    return "home.jsp";
}
```

but instead it goes to my index.html page instead of going to home.jsp, and if i create a controller for my index.html page like this

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String showIndex() {
       logger.info("***INDEX***");

        return "index.html";
    }
```

gives me the following error:

"HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="index.html", line 56 - column 4"

i think that this error is beacuse i am using thymeleaf and in that line i have a `<img>` tag open without a close `</img>` tag.

My question is why my index.html page works if i DONT create a controller and it works FINE, but if i create a controller like i am suppose to do it dont work.

I only have one viewResolver in my config class and is a thymeleaf view resolver, how can this index.html is showing without problems if i only have one resolver

this is my config class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.myapp"})
@Configuration
public class ConfigApp extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
@Bean 
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
 //     resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

   @Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource() {
     ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new                           ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages/messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);// # -1 : never reload, 0 always reload
    return messageSource;
}
    @Bean 
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.setMessageSource(messageSource());

        return engine;
    }

    @Bean 
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCache(false);
        return resolver;
    }
```

and this is my webInitializer class

```
public class InitiaApp extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { ConfigRoot.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { ConfigApp .class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
}
```

and my configRoot class

```
@Configuration
public class ConfiguracionRoot {

}
```

Comment: I guess web server is still trying to use sensible defaults to display welcome page. In your case, since the web server can locate index.html in your root context, it just displays the page with out sending the request to spring controller. In the second case, you are actually calling the controller that returns a thymeleaf view. Thymeleaf requires a well formed xml to properly display in web browser. If you remove index.html and use some other view names, everything should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

When you are not using a controller your not using the Thymeleaf view resolver. This means that the browser is the one translating the html file which much more forgiving, and not required to the rigorousness of HTML 5. While using the Controller you are forced to use the Thymeleaf view resolver. In your view resolver you have your template mode set to HTML5. Also Thymeleaf requires you to use well formed XML which means every open tag needs a closing tag. Read 1.2 of the Thymeleaf documentation for further clarification. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html

Comment: You should give your answer some more detail